# Difference between 2 squared numbers

Tags: javascript

[How do I add commas in between the inputs to make the function work?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zapA1.png)

```
 function square(num) {
    var items=str.split("")
    return Math.abs(num*num - num2*num2)
  }

 square(4 2);
```

Comment: What do you mean? It's working perfectly fine.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the return value of square, ie there is no output.

Comment: You're going to want to edit this again. Just grab the code and put it in the code block (5? spaces) and then explain your problem. Just a link to an image is prone to expiration of the link/image and then this question is incredibly vague with answers

Comment: should be return Math.abs(items[0]*items[0] - items[1]*items[1])

Comment: and your call should be square('4 2'); and then there's the matter of where the square is outputted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```js
function square(num, num2) {
  return Math.abs(num*num - num2*num2);
}

console.log(square(4, 2));
console.log(square(2, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math absolute function:

```
function square(num, num2) {
  var sq1 = num * num,
      sq2 = num2 * num2;
  return Math.abs(sq2-sq1);
}
```

To handle the problem that you didn't include in your question, you can pass a *string* into the square function, and handle like so:

```
function square(NUMBERS_STRING) {
  var numbers = NUMBERS_STRING.split(" "),
      sq1 = numbers[0] * numbers[0],
      sq2 = numbers[1] * numbers[1];
  return Math.abs(sq2-sq1);
}
```

Please, don't confused `square("4 2")` with `square(4 2)`.

The second is not valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

May be worth pointing out that calling this function "square" may be a bad idea. If someone isn't used to your code and they see this function, are they going to know what it does outright? Maybe diffOfSquares(num, num2)?

My recommendation is to have the real mathematic function that'd be reusable in 99% of use cases:

```
function square(num, num2) {
  num *= num;
  num2 *= num2;
  return Math.abs(num-num2);
}
```

And then for your overload call the above. Reason for this is that if something were to ever happen and the underlying logic found in function square(num, num2) required modifying, you would only modify it in one case and not for it plus every other overload. Here's how I'd do it for your current case:

```
function square(str) {
  var items = str.split(" ");
  return square(items[0], items[1]);
}
```

Optionally, but for the sake of reusability, what happens in the future if we get a string where they're pipe delimited? Comma delimited? I wouldn't want to break the code that assumed spacing, so I might modify that function to be:

```
function square(str, delim = " ") {
  var items = str.split(delim);
  return square(items[0].trim(), items[1].trim());
}
```

So if I call it, I could do:

```
square("4 2", " "); // space delimited
square("4 2"); // space delimited for legacy items
square("4, 2", ","); // comma delimited
square("4|2", "|"); // pipe delimited
```